# docker-php-ext-install - sources still not found despite extension is installed

Tags: php, docker

I am trying to install extenion in the docker PHP image. I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential cmake g++ libboost-dev libboost-system-dev \
    libboost-filesystem-dev libexpat1-dev zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev \
    libbz2-dev libpq-dev libproj-dev \
    git sudo wget postgresql-server-dev-all python-pyosmium osmium-tool

RUN docker-php-ext-install dba
RUN docker-php-ext-install pgsql

RUN printf '<Directory "/srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build/website"> \n\
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews \n\
  AddType text/html   .php \n\
  DirectoryIndex search.php \n\
  Require all granted \n\
</Directory> \n\
\n\
Alias /nominatim /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build/website \n' > /etc/apache2/conf-available/nominatim.conf

RUN a2enconf nominatim
RUN service apache2 stop
RUN service apache2 start

WORKDIR /srv/nominatim
RUN wget https://nominatim.org/release/Nominatim-3.2.0.tar.bz2
RUN tar xf Nominatim-3.2.0.tar.bz2
RUN mv Nominatim-3.2.0 Nominatim

WORKDIR /srv/nominatim/Nominatim
RUN mkdir build

WORKDIR /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build
RUN cmake ..
RUN make

RUN tee settings/local.php << $"EOF \n\
<?php \n\
 @define('CONST_Website_BaseURL', '/nominatim/'); \n\
EOF"
```

The problem is that despite extensions are installed and their ini files are listed by phpinfo, the extension doesn't work:

```
Warning: require_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/lib/db.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/lib/db.php on line 3
```

It seems like the DB.php indeed does not exist at all (or I couldn't find them), despite that the extension seems to be installed - as the .so file is in its place as well.

EDIT: I've pasted the full Dockerfile above. I am actually trying to build the Nominatim image that will be composed with another image containing the PostgreSQL with the OSM data.

Comment: Please provide the full Dockerfile. It seems that you don't copy DB.php which is part of the application source, not an extension

Comment: @Thomas, I've updated th question. I don't thin application sources are faulty (at least I hope they are not), because the PHP code comes only from Nominatim. I haven't modified the sources in any way.

Comment: I suspect that you need to install the PEAR:DB package as well, `pear install DB`

Comment: The problem is that this docker image contains PHP build compiled from source and not from packages. Therefore I have install extensions using the docker-php-ext-install script, which does not allow me to install PEAR - or at least I don't know how to do it.

Trying to install any extension for package yields "No installation candidate".